# Error with the eval module in python

Tags: python, module, eval

my computer science class is doing a practice programming task, we need to create a program that asks ten random questions to test the arithmetic skills of the students. I have made separate variables for the two numbers in each question and one for a random operation. This is my code, i am using python 3.5 and i keep getting errors. Can anyone see where i have gone wrong... i think it is with the use of the eval module.

```
    #This is where the import commands go
from random import randint
import random




#This is a set list of variables for each question (21 in total as 2 for each question and operation)

operation = ['x', '-', '+']
q1p1 = (randint(0,100))
q1p2 = (randint(0,100))


#This variable stores the users score
score = 0


#This changes the randomly generated numbers into strings, then evauates them as maths equations so it knows the answers.
#Also it stores the whole of each question as a variable, making it easier to code.
question1 = eval(str(q1p1) + operation + str(q1p2))


#This asks for the user’s name

name = input("What is your forename (With No Caps?)")
surname = input("What is your surname (With No Caps?)")


#This prints a welcome message, personalised with the user's name

print("Welcome to your test," + name)


#Information about how to answer questions

print('''Throughout your test you will be asked a series of questions.
These questions will be randomly generated and are designed to test your basic arithmetic skills.
Please enter your answers in integer form.
EG. if the question was 5 + 5, you would enter 10 with no spaces or extra characters.''')



#First question

print (question1)
answer1 = input("What is the answer to the above question?")
if (question1) == True:
    print("Well done, you got it correct!")
    (score) + 1
```

Comment: `operation = ['x', '-', '+']` change to `operation = random.choice(['*', '-', '+'])` . Which return a string. In your code tries to append with list.

Comment: thanks bro will add it when i get home!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and got the following error:

> Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

for the line:

```
question1 = eval(str(q1p1) + operation + str(q1p2))
```

Operation is a list, you're trying to print out a list of operations in your string. This isn't going to work as you expect it to, you need to select an individual operation, e.g.:

```
question1 = eval(str(q1p1) + str(operation[2]) + str(q1p2))
```

I don't think your program works as you expect it to. You're trying to make a question string and then you check if this "question1" is true? Here are some steps as to what your program should do:

1. Select an operation from your operation list, you can't use the entire list.
2. Generate two random numbers (look up the Python 'random' class)
3. Check for the operation you selected from the list, perform the calculation of the two numbers with this operation
4. Get input from the user (look up the Python 'input' method)
5. Check if the users input matches the correct answer

   ```
   import random

   operations = ['+','-','x']

   operation = random.choice(operations)

   number1 = random.randrange(0,10)
   number2 = random.randrange(0,10)

   score = 0

   answer = None

   if operation == '+':
       answer = number1 + number2
   elif operation == '-':
       answer = number1 - number2
   elif operation == 'x':
       answer = number1 * number2

   user_answer = input("What is " + str(number1) + " " + operation + " " + str(number2) + "?")
   user_answer = float(user_answer)

   if user_answer == answer:
       print("Correct")
       score = score+1
   ```

Also the line

```
score + 1
```

Doesn't do what you think it does, it simply takes score and adds one to it, it doesn't do anything with this value. To increase score you need to reassign it back into score:

```
score = score + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, Is there no way I can generate a random operation and insert it into the maths question, then check if the users input is correct or not?

Comment: Check the answer again ive added some code that does most of what you ask. You'll need to modify it yourself though to do this on a loop

Answer (score 0):

"x" is not the multiply operator in python, use '*'

When debugging its a good idea to use print to show the value of interesting variables in your code.

For example when you see a error at a line in the code and you are not sure why. Try printing the values that the line uses.

For example change the code to something like this:

```
print( 'eval called with', str(q1p1) + operation + str(q1p2) )
question1 = eval(str(q1p1) + operation + str(q1p2))
```